# Error al consumer un método get de un api con basic auth

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

tengo un error a la hora de consumir un metodo get de una api que desarrolle la cual tanto en postman como en el navegador funcionan. quiero consumirla en una aplicacion de escritorio vb.net. y me sale error en la linea " Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync("/api/Cliente")" que dice "An error occurred while sending the request" no se si sea porque estoy haciendo pruebas desde localhost. gracias de antemano.
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
Public Async Function GetCliente(Usuario As String, Clave As String) As Task
Try
    ' Crear una instancia de HttpClient y establecer la dirección base de la API
    Dim client As New HttpClient With {
        .BaseAddress = New Uri("https://localhost:44352")
    }

    ' Agregar las credenciales de autenticación básica a la cabecera Authorization del cliente
    Dim authenticationString As String = $"{Usuario}:{Clave}"
    Dim base64EncodedAuthenticationString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString))
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString)

    ' Realizar una solicitud GET al recurso deseado
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync("/api/Cliente")

    ' Procesar la respuesta
    If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        Dim content As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Else
        Dim Respuesta = response.StatusCode
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Function

Comment: si estas haciendo pruebas, hazlas primero de forma sincrona (sin await), y mira el resultado. (sin await y sin los readAsync correspondientes)

Comment: Probé el código y funciona correctamente

Comment: muchas gracias Jakala Funciono correctamente.